# Finite Difference Solution to Heat Equation

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

Practicing finite difference implementation and I cannot figure out why my solution looks so strange. Code taken from: http://people.bu.edu/andasari/courses/numericalpython/Week9Lecture15/PythonFiles/FTCS_DirichletBCs.py.

Note: I'm using this lecture example for the heat equation not the reaction-diffusion equation!

I haven't learned the relevant mathematics so this could be why!

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import math as mth
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pylab as plb
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg


# First start with diffusion equation with initial condition  u(x, 0) = 4x - 4x^2 and u(0, t) = u(L, t) = 0
# First discretise the domain [0, L] X [0, T]
# Then discretise the derivatives
# Generate algorithm:
# 1. Compute initial condition for all i
# 2. For all n:
#    2i. Compute u_i^{n + 1} for internal space points
#   2ii. Set boundary values for i = 0 and i = N_x



M = 40 # number of grid points for space interval
N = 70 # ''     '' ''   ''     ''  time ''

x0 = 0
xL = 1 # unit grid differences

dx = (xL - x0) / (M - 1) # space step

t0 = 0
tF = 0.2

dt = (tF - t0) / (N - 1)

D = 0.3 # thermal diffusivity 

a = D * dt / dx**2

# Create grid
tspan = np.linspace(t0, tF, N)
xspan = np.linspace(x0, xL, M)


# Initial matrix solution
U = np.zeros((M, N))

# Initial condition
U[:, 0] = 4*xspan - 4*xspan**2
# Boundary conditions
U[0, :] = 0
U[-1, 0] = 0

# Discretised derivative formula
for k in range(0, N-1):
    for i in range(1, M-1):
        U[i, k+1] = a * U[i-1, k] + (1 - 2 * a) * U[i, k] + a * U[i + 1, k]


X, T = np.meshgrid(tspan, xspan)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, T, U, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.set_xticks([0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2])

ax.set_xlabel('Space')
ax.set_ylabel('Time')
ax.set_zlabel('U')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

edit: Changed therm diff value to correct one.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  If you haven't learned the underlying mathematics, then you have more work to do before posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the time step length. If you look at the differential equation, the numerics become unstable for `a>0.5`. Translated this means for you that roughly `N > 190`. I get a nice picture if I increase your `N` to such value.

However, I thing somewhere the time and space axes are swapped (if you try to interpret the graph then, i.e. boundary conditions and expected dampening of profile over time). I cannot figure out right now why.

**Edit**: Actually, you swap `T` and `X` when you do `meshgrid`. This should work:

```
    N = 200

...
...

    T, X = np.meshgrid(tspan, xspan)

...

    surf = ax.plot_surface(T, X, U, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

...

    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax.set_ylabel('Space')
```

Comment: Thanks, this clears up a lot. Stability was the most confusing part for me. I'll check out a numerical analysis textbook again!